# reference algorithm for weighted voronoi diagrams?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, geometry, voronoi

Can someone point me to a reference implementation on how to construct a (multiplicatively and/or additively) weighted voronoi diagram, which is preferably based on Fortune's voronoi algorithm?

**My goal**:
Given a set of points(each point has a weight) and a set of boundary edges(usually a rectangle) I want to construct a weighted voronoi diagram using either python or the processing.org-framework. Here is an [example](http://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2008/05/03/business/20080403_SPENDING_GRAPHIC.html?_r=0).

**What I have worked on so far**:
So far I have implemented Fortune's algorithm as well as the "centroidal voronoi tessellation"  presented in [Michael Balzer's paper](http://graphics.uni-konstanz.de/publikationen/2005/voronoi_treemaps/Balzer%20et%20al.%20--%20Voronoi%20Treemaps.pdf). Algorithm 3 states how the weights need to be adjusted, however, when I implement this my geometry does not work anymore. To fix this the sweep-line algorithm has to be updated to take weights into account, but I have been unable to do this so far.
Hence I would like to see how other people solved this problem.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For additively weighted Voronoi Diagram: [Remember that a power diagram in dimension n is only a(n unweighted) Voronoi diagram in dimension n+1](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.104.678&rep=rep1&type=pdf).

For that, just recall that the Voronoi diagram of a point set is invariant if you add any constant to the coordinates, and that the weighted Voronoi diagram can thus be written as a non weighted Voronoi diagram using the coordinates, for example in 2D lifted to 3D:
(x_i, y_i, sqrt(C - w_i))
where w_i is the weight of the seed, and C is any arbitrarily large constant (in practice, one just small enough such that C-w_i is positive).
Once your diagram is computed, just discard the last component.

So, basically, you only need to find a library that is able to handle Voronoi diagrams in dimension n+1 compared to your problem. CGAL can do that. This also makes the implementation extremely easy.

Answer (score 3):

This computation is not easy, but it is available in CGAL.  See [the manual pages here.](http://www.cgal.org/Manual/latest/doc_html/cgal_manual/packages.html#part_X)

---

[image: From CGAL manual]

---

See also the [Effective Computational Geometry](https://www-sop.inria.fr/prisme/ECG/) project, which employs and
supports CGAL:

---

[image: Monique]

Answer (score 2):

There is little `off-the-shelf' open source code out there, for the case where distances to the centers are weighted with a multiplicative factor.
To my knowledge, none of the current CGAL packages covers this case.

Takashi Ohyama's beautifully colorful website provides java implementations 
http://www.nirarebakun.com/voro/emwvoro.html
for up to 100 points with a SIMPLE algorithm (Euclidean and Manhattan distances).
There is also a paper describing this simple intersection algorithm and an approximate implementation within O(n^3) time, as a plugin to TerraView.
However, I cannot find the source of this plugin in the TerraView / TerraLib repository:
http://www.geoinfo.info/geoinfo2011/papers/mauricio1.pdf

Aurenhammer and Edelsbrunner describe an optimal n^2 time algorithm, but I'm unaware of available code of that.

Answer (score 0):

If you are comfortable digging into [Octave](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Voronoi-Diagrams.html), you could reference the code provided in their [library](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/download.html).

Comment: Also, the library often provides external resources for specific algorithms or implementations that may be helpful.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I have looked at the the [Octave documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Voronoi-Diagrams.html), but unfortunately I did not see any API's describing how I can construct weighted voronois. It seems to only support general voronoi diagrams for e.g. nearest neighbor analysis. Did I miss something?